# How to display a UItableView in UicollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview, datasource

So I have collection view with 3 cells, each of which has a tableview in it.  Obviously, each collection view cell has to load it's table view with different data for the table view cells.

My first thought was to make the collection view the delegate and datasrouce of the table view, but even so, the datasource will need to know which collection view cell is being loaded.

Also thought of making a separate class for the DS and delegate for both the collection view and the table view, but then again, I'm stuck on how the tableview DS will know which collection view cell it's being loaded from.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

After I make the assignment, the datasource field is nil.  So what am I missing here?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) else {
        return UICollectionViewCell.init()
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    cell.theTableView.dataSource = RequestedTableDataSource.init()
    cell.theTableView.delegate = self

    cell.theTableView.reloadData()

    return cell
}

class RequestedTableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 16
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RequestedCell") as? IntervieologistRequestedCell else {
        return UITableViewCell.init()
    }

    cell.setupCellFor(name: "Dan", image: UIImage.init(named: "dan")!)

    return cell
}
```

}

If I do this:

```
let foo = RequestedTableDataSource.init()
    cell.myTableView.dataSource = foo
```

then the dataSource field is set, numberOfRows gets called, but cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't.

Comment: Make your CollectionView cell as dataSource for your TableView, and in cellForItemAt of collectionView call reloadTableview... I hope its helpful, please comment if you need more help

Comment: Found it.  I need a strong reference to a RequstedTableDataSource object to hand off to the dataSource field of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tableView.tag to an unique integer and identify it later in the delegate methods using that, but I would recommend keeping a seperate datasource/delegate for each tableview, much cleaner.

Don't make the CollectionView or any other View object the datasource/delegate.

eg set

```
collectionViewCell.tableView.tag = index;
collectionViewCell.tableView.delegate = commonDelegate;
```

or

```
collectionViewCell.tableView.delegate = uniqueDelegate; // Better choice
```